# How can i read and execute a file from the workspace in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm trying to read and execute the file from workspace for a jenkins pipeline. I tried using "readFile" function but it is just reading the contents of the file. I want the contents to get executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the 'sh' step: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script